# Configuring ntp server on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntp

I am trying to configure the time on my system, as per one of the `ntp` servers provided on net. However, the time doesn't change. I am doing this on Ubuntu 12.04 which is installed in Oracle `VirtualBox` with Windows 7 as the host system.

```
saasbook@saasbook:~$ su 
Password: 
root@saasbook:/home/ubuntu# pgrep ntpd
1392
root@saasbook:/home/ubuntu# cd ..
root@saasbook:/home# cd ..
root@saasbook:/# ls
bin    dev   initrd.img  media  proc  sbin     sys  var
boot   etc   lib         mnt    root  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lost+found  opt    run   srv      usr
root@saasbook:/# vi etc/ntp.conf
```

In there, I add one server as shown

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

# The server specified by me
server in.pool.ntp.org

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.


server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
```

After that I save the changes and restart the ntp as follows

```
root@saasbook:/# /etc/init.d/ntp restart
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ] 
 * Starting NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ]
```

Even after doing all these, the time on my system does not change. Is there something I am mising ?

Comment: It probably won't work because you're on a virtual server and you can't adjust the clock of the Windows host. What happens if you try this as root? ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com

Comment: It gives me this time `8 Dec 21:46:41 ntpdate[2498]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting`. However, the time in my country is different.

Comment: Seems that you're trying to use ntpd and ntpdate at the same time. ntpdate is for manual updates, ntpd is a daemon which does updates automatically.

Comment: One more thing -- why did you decide that your time doesn't change? Could you show "grep ntpd /var/log/daemon"?

Comment: Please add the output of `ntpq -p`.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.